# What can conclude about $[G:H]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Assume that $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, and that $G$ contains elements $a_1, a_2,...,a_n$ such that $a_i a_j^{-1} \notin H $ for $1\leq i < n, 1 \leq j <n $, and $i \neq j$. What can you conclude about $[G:H]$?

My answer is:

$[G:H] = {e}$

I came up with this answer since I see from what is given that we have no

$a=hb $  for some $h \in H$

therefore, $Ha \neq Hb$

and in this case, the identity is the only coset to the subgroup $H$.

Comment: $[G:H]$ should be a number, not an element of $G$.

Comment: It is given that there exists an element $a_i a_j^{-1} \notin H$ (assuming $n \geq 2$). Then $a_i a_j^{-1} H$ is a different coset than $H$ right? Also what are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @ Arthur: $a, b \in G$

Comment: @ Alex Kruckman: I meant to specify the elements that exist in the coset

Comment: Are you saying that there exist no $a,b \in G, h \in H$ such that $a = hb$? Surely $a = b = h = 1$ works.

Comment: @ Arthur: The theory at hand says "if H is a subgroup of a group G, and a,b \in G, then the following four conditions are equivalent:

1- $ab^-1 \in H$
2- $a = hb$ for some $h \in H$
3- $a \in Hb$
4- $Ha = Hb$ 

As a consequence, the right coset of $H$ to wich a belongs is $Ha$

Comment: I have no clue at all what you're trying to say. Please rephrase your argument.

Comment: @ Arthur: I'm trying to use these equivalent statements to prove that the coset of H is only the identity.

Comment: If $n \geq 2$, then clearly there is an element $a_i a_j^{-1} \notin H$, and there are two different cosets $H$ and $a_i a_j^{-1} H$. So what you are trying to prove is false.

Answer (score 1):

You can conclude that $[G:H] \geq n$ : In fact the cosets
$$
\{Ha_1, Ha_2, \ldots, Ha_n\}
$$
are all distinct by the given condition.

Comment: can we have $[G:H] \geq n$ where $n = |G|$ ?

Comment: Dear Prahlad, the distinct classes are $Ha_i$.